# f# function that returns a generic function

Tags: generics, f#

I would like to do the following :

```
module private repo =
    let SaveEvts<'T> (conn:IConnection) mydata =  
        async {
            let! result = conn.SaveAsync(mydata)
        }

let SaveAsync (conn:IConnection) = repo.SaveEvts conn
```

so that I could open a single connection to my db and then have in closure my connection whenever I want to save some type T data. e.g :

```
type Foo = { idPhoto : Guid }
type Bar = { reason : string }

let myConnection = new Connection(connectionString)
let save = SaveAsync myConnection
let doProgram =
    save<Foo>({idPhoto = 212313})
    save<Bar>({idPhoto = 212313})
```

This is fantasy writing, I do not know if it compiles: My issues here are

1. Is there a way to do what I want to achieve , ie a normal function that returns a generic function.
2. if it is doable, is it advisable?

I would like to avoid writing :

```
let saveFoo = SaveEvts<Foo> (conn:IConnection) 
let saveBar = SaveEvts<Bar> (conn:IConnection)
```

but maybe there is no other way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write a function that returns a generic function in F#. There are two ways to solve this:

- You can write a function that returns a simple object with a generic method and then use this object to do all the work
- You can define a new generic function that captures an existing connection

So, the code in your second snippet would not work, but you can do:

```
let myConnection = new Connection(connectionString)
let save arg = SaveAsync myConnection arg

save {FooProperty = 212313}
save {BarProperty = 212313}
```

Here, `save` is defined as a function and so it can be generic, but it can still capture the existing opened connection `myConnection` and use it for all the different arguments that you give it.